# Assign a class to a child if condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

How would I go about giving a child element a class if the parent element contained style="display: none;" and a certain class?

For example, I want:

```
<div style="display: none;" class="hidden">
  <a href="#">Hidden</a>
</div>
```

to be:

```
<div style="display: none;" class="hidden">
  <a href="#" class="new-class">Hidden</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need to write javascript for this functionality I believe. Are you requesting the exact code in here? You will probably need an id for the item to be watched, and also a script section where you define your function. Then you call that for body onload.

Comment: My biggest confusion is how do you target style="display: none;" and how do you specify class="hidden"'s a child?

Comment: try `if ( a.is(':visible')) {
   a.parent().addClass('backgroundfilter');
}`

Comment: @DipeshParmar - this necessitates JQuery, which isn't tagged and may not be in use here

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox well see in Nathan answer OP said `HE IS OPEN TO JQUERY`... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes there's only one `div` on the page. If there isn't you'll need to loop through elements and perform very similar logic.

```
<div style="display: none;" class="hidden">
  <a href="#">Hidden</a>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

        if(el.style.display == 'none'){
            el.children[0].setAttribute('class', 'someclass');
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

Another solution using `querySelectorAll`:

```
<div style="display: none;" class="hidden">
  <a href="#">Hidden</a>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        var els = document.querySelectorAll('div.hidden[style*="display: none"]');

        for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            els[i].children[0].setAttribute('class', 'someclass');
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3f8zQ/

Comment: There are several divs on the page with the class "hidden" that's why it also needs to target the div with class "hidden" and style="display: none;"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery:

```
var hidden = $('.hidden');
if (hidden.css('display') === 'none') {
    hidden.children('a').addClass('new-class');
}
```

Or it sounds like you want to target the child element and check its parent, in which case you'll need some way to reference that child element (an id or a class), and then you can do `child.parent()`.

You can do it in vanilla JS easily too but it will depend on what browsers you have to support (whether you can use `document.getElementsByClassName`, etc.)

Comment: jQuery isn't mentioned or tagged.

Comment: True, but it's an extremely commonly used library. As I said in the answer, if implementing in vanilla JS you need to take into consideration what browsers to support, so a concise answer is more difficult.

Comment: I'm open to jQuery, thanks. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: This seems like it should work but for some reason is not... I have the a element nested in about 5 divs after the one I need to call. Could this be an issue?

Comment: I can also target the child with #hikashop_main_image_link if that might make it more solid.

Comment: Oh yeah, if the nesting is deeper than one level you need to use `.find()` instead of `.children()` if you're going outside-in, or `.parents()` instead of `.parent()` if you're going inside-out.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can simply do this with `$(':hidden > a')`:

http://jsfiddle.net/t8K5e/